# Multithread superlinear performance implementation with CPU boost mode consideration

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, boost

I am studying the  class in C++11 by using MinGW 4.8.1 lib on WIN7 64bit OS.

The CPU is ARK | Intel® Core™ i7-820QM Processor, which has four physical cores with 8M cache and supports maximum eight threads. This CPU has base operation frequency at 1.73 GHz if four cores are used simultaneously and can be boosted to 3.08 GHz if only one core is used.

The main target of my studying is that I am going to implement a Multithread test program to demonstrate super-linear performance increases as the number of the thread increases.

Here, the SUPER-linear term means exactly 4 speedup times (maybe 3.8 times acceptable) when employing four threads compared to single thread, not 3.2 or 3.5 times.

The codes and results are pasted here,

```
inline void count(int workNum)  // some working to do . 
                                //These codes are extracted from a real application except that the count function do some "meaningful" job and 
                                //these codes have identical speedup ratio as my real application.
{
     int s=0;  
     for(int i=0;i<workNum;++i)
       ++s;    
}

inline void devide(int numThread)  // create multiThreads [1,7] to do same amount task 
{
    int max = 100000000;
    typedef std::vector<std::thread>  threadList;
    threadList list;
    for(int i=1;i<=numThread;++i){
       list.push_back(std::thread(count,max/numThread));    
    } 
    std::for_each(list.begin(),list.end(),std::mem_fun_ref(&std::thread::join));   
}

inline void thread_efficiency_load()  // to start test 
{       
   for(int i=7;i>0;--i)
   {
     std::cout<< "*****************************************" << std::endl; 
     std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> start, end;
     start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

     devide(i); // this is the work load to be measured, which i is the number of thread  

     end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
     std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_seconds = end-start;
     std::cout << "thread num=#" << i << "  time=" <<  elapsed_seconds.count() << std::endl;      
   }   
}
```

The output is:

```
 The time unit is seconds,

 *****************************************
 thread num=#7  time=0.101006
 *****************************************
 thread num=#6  time=0.0950055
 *****************************************
 thread num=#5  time=0.0910052
 *****************************************
 thread num=#4  time=0.0910052
 *****************************************
 thread num=#3  time=0.102006
 *****************************************
 thread num=#2  time=0.127007
 *****************************************
 thread num=#1  time=0.229013
```

This is very clear that I do not obtain a super-linear performance increases as the number of thread increases. I would like to know why I do not get it. Why ? Why ? Why ?

Some basic things from my mind,

Due to the fact that there are only 4 physical cores, so the maximum speedup should show up when there are four active threads (more threads does not really help a lot). There are only 2.4 times speed up by using four cores compared to the single, where 4 times speed-up is expected. I hope the above implementation does block the 4 times speed-up due to memory issue (cache paging) because all variables are local variables.

By considering the CPU boost mode, the CPU increases operating frequency to 3.07 GHz when there is only one core busy, where is a ratio of 1.7 ( base operating frequency of cores is 1.79 GHz), 2.4 * 1.7 is about 4 as excepted, does it really mean that 2.4 time speedup is the maximum speedup can be made compared to the boost single thread mode.

I will be very appreciated that you can answer,

1) In the above implementation, are there some variables located on the same cache line, which results a lot of paging between multithread to reduce the performance ?
2) How to modify the above codes to achieve super-linear performance (4 times speedup compared to the single thread) as the number of the threads increases ?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Maybe I overlooked something, but why wuold there be any chance to get a SUPER-linear (more than linear) increase of performance, when - even in the optimal case - the number of parallel available instructions grows at most linear with the number of threads and the time a single operation takes increases due to lower clock frequency.

Comment: @MikeMB, you are totally and completely right. The SUPER-linear means exactly 4 times (maybe 3.9 times acceptable), not 3.2 or 3.5 times. It can not be more than 4 times. I add this to post as well.

Comment: @MikeMB Superlinear speedups are rare but occasionally happen. Usually the responsible is the cache / memory subsystem. But yes, it is sometimes possible to get more than a linear speedup, even though it might seem confusing or impossible.

Comment: Are you profiling a debug build or a release one? I'd expect any decent compiler to replace your "work" by a single nop instruction.

Comment: @Park: I know that it is possible in theory, but in the given example the work function doesn't even have to access the memory other than for thread maintenance is very difficult. So I don't believe superlinear speedup is possible (aside from noise)

Comment: @MikeMB, thank you very much for your comment. The above codes are extracted from a real application except that the count function do some "meaningful" job. The above codes have identical speedup ratio as my real application. I do not have profiling tools with me. I could not do it.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a warning up front: arguing about actual performance numbers of a multithreaded Program on a modern x86/x64 system without a RTOS is always a lot of speculation - there are just too many layers between your c/c++ code and the actual operations performed on the processor.

As a rough upper bound estimation, yes, for a ALU(not memory)-bound workload you won't get much more than a 1.73*4 / 3.08 = 2.24 times speedup factor for 4 threads on 4 cores vs 1 thread on one core even in the ideal case. Aside from that, I' argue that your tests "workload" is too small to get meaningfull test results. As mentioned in the comments, a compiler would be allowed to completely replace your workload function with a NOP operation leaving you only with the overhead of creating and joining the threads and your measurement (although I don't think that happened here).